# MS IE & Edge fall back to http/1.1 after Kerberos Negotiate via http/2

Tags: https, kerberos, http2, kerberos-delegation, negotiate

We recently updated our Apache (v 2.4.33) Reverse Proxy to use http/2

MS IE (v 11.431.16299.0) and MS Edge (v 41.16299.402.0) on Win 10E 1709 seem to fall back to http/1.1 after the first request. Both browsers sticks then to http/1.1 and do not change to http/2 even after full refresh with clearing cache.

First request (without the Kerberos Negotiate Authentication Headers) http/2:
[image: first request http/2 the rest http/1.1]

Second request (with the Negotiate Headers) and all further are http/1.1:
[image: second request with auth headers]

When switching to a new tab, the browser directly uses http/2 for all requests, as the authentication process is done via session cookie:
[image: http/2 working in new tab]

Is there any reasonable explanation for this behavior? How can I advise (force) IE/Edge to keep using http/2?

Kerberos Negotiation is easily explained here:
https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/MSDNBlogsFS/prod.evol.blogs.msdn.com/CommunityServer.Blogs.Components.WeblogFiles/00/00/01/47/48/8468.4.png

Comment: IE11 on which version of Windows?

Comment: @Knu I added the versions although I think they don't matter as we experienced the same issues with Win 10E 1608

Answer (score 1):

I might be a bit late but I have encountered the same behaviour and it might be because of this Chromium Bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=832586

Unfortunately it has not been fixed yet.